# What is the difference between the modal presentation style "over current context" and "over fullscreen"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I wonder what the difference between current context and over fullscreen is?

When I switch between them I don't see any changes in my app. All the animations look the same etc.

Comment: See the documentation for `UIModalPresentationStyle`.

Comment: @rmaddy The documentation is very poor, incomplete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**fullScreen:**
The presented view covers the screen `(fullscreen)`.

**currentContext:**
The `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` style covers a specific view controller in your interface. When using the contextual style, you designate which view controller you want to cover by setting its definesPresentationContext property to `true`.

> When presenting a view controller using the
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen style, UIKit normally removes the views
>   of the underlying view controller after the transition animations
>   finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the
>   UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext style instead. You might use
>   that style when the presented view controller has transparent areas
>   that let underlying content show through.

Read more about presenting viewControllers [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html).

Answer (score 27):

There aren't any visual differences if you are presenting a view controller from a view controller that is already in full screen mode. However, if the presenting view controller isn't in full screen mode, the **current context** will make a different. For example:

- Left: before present, the current view controller is not in full screen mode
- Middle: presenting a new view controller with **full screen**
- Right: presenting a new view controller with **current context**

[image]
[image]
[image]

A full list of comparison of different presentation mode available [here on Github](https://github.com/yzhong52/ModalPresentationStyleDemo).

Comment: Thanks. It'd be better if Apple's help doc in Xcode should address that.